# How to get string from file using key value pair?

Tags: c#, .net

I have file here is content of the file:

```
# Web surround localized strings
# English language
#
# Important: This file must be saved with UTF-8 encoding
#

# General

# GeoMarker - temporary pin markup.
SERVERERROR             = Error!Please Contact admin.
ERRORSTACKTRACE         = Stack Trace
```

I need to get massage from the file above according to key.Currently I have in file above `SERVERERROR` and `ERRORSTACKTRACE` keys I need to fetch massege according to keys.

How can I implement it in c#?

Comment: You have 2.3k rep, so you know what's coming: What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck? There are tons of examples about reading files in c# on the web.

Comment: It is also rather easy to think of several ways of parsing the text. Split by `=`, use a Regex. Filter out lines that start with `#`. Why such a `Write the code for me` question?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you please show example?

Comment: Example of what? What is the question? Have you even tried reading the file's lines? If you have 2.3K rep and 18 gold badges you *have* to know how to ask a proper question. You *have* to know this is a badly formed question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int counter = 0;
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file =
            new System.IO.StreamReader("s.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
if(line.Contains("SERVERERROR") || line.Contains("ERRORSTACKTRACE") )
    Console.WriteLine (line);
    counter++;
}
    file.Close();
```

Output:

SERVERERROR             = Error!Please Contact admin.
ERRORSTACKTRACE         = Stack Trace

Moreover to get exact errors:

...

`if(line.Contains("SERVERERROR") || line.Contains("ERRORSTACKTRACE") )`

```
Console.WriteLine (line.Split('=')[1].ToString());
```

...

Comment: I get this value 'SERVERERROR   = Server Error' but I expect to get  the value of this key SERVERERROR (i.e Error!Please Contact admin.)

Comment: Try: Console.WriteLine (line.Split('=')[0].ToString()+" "+line.Split('=')[1].ToString()); OUTPUT: SERVERERROR Error!Please Contact admin.

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
var str = "SERVERERROR             = Error!Please Contact admin."+
                "ERRORSTACKTRACE         = Stack Trace";

    var output = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    foreach(var item in str.Split('.').ToList()){
        var kv = item.Split('=');
        output.Add(kv[0].Trim(),kv[1].Trim());
    }

    Console.WriteLine(output["SERVERERROR"]);
    Console.WriteLine(output["ERRORSTACKTRACE"]);
```

Check this fiddle:
    https://dotnetfiddle.net/5LgiE7

Comment: Not quite. The separator is the newline, not the dot. Your test input doesn't even have newlines. Reading from a file doesn't require splitting lines anyway, you can read individual lines